# How to change icon color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

This is the code snippet

```
ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: controller.items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                      final _item = controller.items[index];
                      if(_item['rota'] == Routes.home){
                          return Obx(() => Container(

                      decoration: (controller.selectedIndex == index)
                                ? const BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(
                                top: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.white),
                                bottom: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            )
                                : null,
                            child: Obx(() =>  Card(
                                color: const Color(0XFF007E94),
                                elevation: 3,

                                child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                    _item['titulo'],
                                    style: TextStyle(color: (controller.selectedIndex == index ) ? Colors.black :  Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  leading: _item['icone'],
                                    onTap: () {
                                      controller.selectedIndex = index ;
                                      Get.toNamed(_item['rota']);
                                    },
                                    selected: controller.selectedIndex == index
                            ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
```

The code snippet that changes the color of the letter is this one.

```
  title: Text( _item['titulo'],
    style: TextStyle(color: (controller.selectedIndex == index ) ? Colors.black :  Colors.white),
                              ),
```

Please, how can I change the icon color taking into account the menu list that is coming from the Page class?

What I need is when the menu is selected the icon color changes to black.

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    items.add(
      {
        'titulo': 'Home',
        'icone': const Icon(
          Icons.house_rounded,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        'rota': Routes.home,
      },
    );

    items.add(
      {
        'titulo': 'Novas Edições',
        'icone': Image.asset(AppImages.novasEdicoes),
        'rota': Routes.newEditions,
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the current index is selected. If so, use *black* color, otherwise, choose the one from your items array.

For your use case, it's really as simple as this:

```
Image.asset(
  AppImages.novasEdicoes, 
  color: index == controller.selectedIndex ? Colors.black : items[index].color
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your try, but it didn't work

Comment: Did the color not change or was there some sort of compiler error? Does the color change if you do not select it from the items array?

Comment: This is my controller => https://ideone.com/oACHrr   This is my page => https://ideone.com/GG1VBy

Comment: I believe you'll need to change up the ListView architecture a little. ListView.builder doesn't react to changes in the data it is initially given. Maybe wrapping the ListView.builder with the Obx() widget wrapper (since you're using GetX) will allow the list to rebuild and respond to your desired changes.